# ubuntu 20.04 sensors ( lm-sensor ) to syslog - Missing sensord

Tags: 20.04, syslog, lm-sensors

I found an article about sensord missing from v20.04.From a while ago called what is the new equiv of sensord.
In it there is a comment :

On Ubuntu 20.04 it is also missing. It's not in lm-sensors and I have no files I can locate with sensord in the name. Additionally a check with apt-file shows references from SELinux-related packages to sensord profiles but no actual sensord anymore. –
0xC0000022L
May 19, 2021 at 18:17

Has anyone worked out how to get lmsensor - sensor data into syslog ?
Ive done quite a few googles and most follow the lines of why not use psensor and not really answer the question.
In my case its on a server , no gui and unless needed no monitor.

If sensord no longer exists I guess I could run a script from cron , probably use something such as awk to extract bits and then use logger to write a message to syslog but that does seem a messy solution.

Im retired now but when I had a real job, I was a big believer in if your solution looks too complex, is difficult for others to understand or is messy then it may work but its not a good solution :)

In the old days we used to use syslog for loads of things which made it easy to see whats going on with any number of systems all in one place. On the down side, it can be a swine to process the messages.
Anyway if anyone knows what has either replaced sensord or the new way of doing things would you please give me some pointers.

Since retiring its easy to loose touch with whats going on and changing :)

Thanks
J